# Sidebar pushed below content in individual post (Wordpress)

Tags: css, wordpress, width, sidebar, wordpress-thesis-theme

I'm designing a blog in Wordpress using the Thesis Framework and there is an issue that I just can't seem to find a fix to:

Basically everything is fine on the main page, but when I go into any individual post, the side bar is getting pushed off and showing up right down the button of the page (below the comments).

It's pretty obvious that there is some kind of sizing/width issue and I've played around with a lot of the widths in firebug but just can't seem to find where it's going wrong. I can't find a difference between the main page and post pages either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! A specific solution would be ideal because I've already spent a lot of time tinkering with it to try and address the issue.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem as well with the thesis framework. I found two reasons where it produced a similar mistake on my blog:

The first reason is that the sidebar + content area is bigger than you container. That would make the sidebar go below the the content. Make sure also that the content of the sidebar is also smaller than the sidebar. I had a Facebook box in the sidebar that was bigger, thus pushed the whole sidebar below the content.

An other reason was a plugin that I had installed. If you have any plugins installed try and see if one of those is interfering with the sidebar layout.

If that doesn't work you can also post a snippet of the code so that I can look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I often have this problem when editing a page in html (text) mode and forget a closing tag, most notably a .  If using tables, a missing ,  or similar will cause this.

So, in brief, make sure all your opening tags have a corresponding close tag.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the html is syntax-error free. I had the same problem and the culprit was a wrong closing tag (`<b/>`)